# Hide / show dynamically generated table columns with right / left animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on the following - working - code:

[See it on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdcjy1mg/1/)

The HTML is dynamically generated from a XML file which is transformed to HTML by a XSL file. Due to the fact that the number of columns my vary, I used the **:nth-child** in the JQuery code to hide/show the columns by clicking the relative checkbox.

As I'm not very good with JQuery I'm stuck on the animation part. **I would like to add an animation to the hide/show action**, for example that the checked/unchecked column appears and disappears from left to right.

```
body {
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.htable {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.htable tr, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.ctable {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

<body>
        <table class="htable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>GoPro 1</th>
                    <th>GoPro 2</th>
                    <th>GoPro 3</th>
                    <th>GoPro 4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <table class="ctable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="1">GoPro 1</th>
                    <th colspan="1">GoPro 2</th>
                    <th colspan="1">GoPro 3</th>
                    <th colspan="1">GoPro 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="separator">Video resolution</th>
                    <td class="values odd separator">4K</td>
                    <td class="values odd separator">4K</td>
                    <td class="values odd separator">4K</td>
                    <td class="values odd separator">4K</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <td class="values odd">Ultra wide</td>
                    <td class="values odd">Ultra wide</td>
                    <td class="values odd">Ultra wide</td>
                    <td class="values odd">Ultra wide</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <td class="values odd">3840x2160</td>
                    <td class="values odd">3840x2160</td>
                    <td class="values odd">3840x2160</td>
                    <td class="values odd">3840x2160</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){

                /* Show hide columns */
                var f = function() {
                        var index = $(":checkbox").index(this) + 2;
                        $(".ctable > * > * > :nth-child(" + index + ")").toggle(this.checked);
                };

                $(":checkbox").click(f).each(f);
            });
      </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/cdcjy1mg/7/

```
 $(".ctable > * > * > :nth-child(" + index + ")").toggleClass('hidden');
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
   width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.htable tr, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
```

Comment: Using `font-size: 0` is ingenious.  +1!

Answer (score 1):

How about this ? http://jsfiddle.net/cdcjy1mg/2/

```
$(".ctable > * > * > :nth-child(" + index + ")").toggle("slow");
```

You can put the animation you want. Take a look at jquery effect.

Hope this help.

Comment: Oh! I was getting mad as I didn't know where to put the '(this.checked)' part!
Is it possible to hide all the column by sliding it on the left? toggle("slow") isn't so smooth.

Comment: If you look at toggle, the one with toggle(true/false) doesn't accept any other option.